# Missing template - perplexed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a simple Amazon search app which works adequately and I am now trying to merge the functionality into another app which uses OmniAuth. Problem is I am getting a template missing error when I perform the search in the new app: Missing template books/search, application/search ...

Here is the routes.rb for the first app:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books

  root :to => "books#index"
  match '/search', to: 'books#search', via: :get
```

The books_controller.rb has

```
def search

  @allbooks << newbook
  ## no redirect statements but results displays fine...

 end
```

And here is the routes.rb for the app I am trying to add the search box:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
      resources :users
      resources :reviews

      resources :books

      root :to => "books#index"

      match '/search', to: 'books#search', via: :get
```

I have confirmed that the search function is getting executed but now I am getting the template missing error.. The application.html.erb in both cases has the following section which displays fine in the original search app:

```
           <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div>
            <% flash.each do |name,msg| %>
              <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        <%= yield %>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Slavko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run search action in the books controller it will (by default) look in app/views/books for a file named search.html.erb (or whatever template you're using).

I'm guessing you're not using this in your local version so didn't upload it. Just a blank file should do it?

Not tested but you may be able to get round this by adding the following into your controller:

```
render nothing: true, layout: true
```